# Next without For Compile Error (But I have both..)

Tags: excel, vba

```
' Loop through filenames and return within an array
For Each MyFile In MyFiles
    If InStr(1, MyFile.Name, FileExt) <> 0 Then
          Dim toSplitFileName As Variant

          toSplitFileName = Split(MyFile.Name, "-")

          For Each dept In deptCodes
            MsgBox ("True")

            If dept = toSplitFileName(3) Then
          Next dept

          Result(i) = MyFile.Name

          i = i + 1
    End If

Next MyFile
```

The error is happening at "For Each dept In deptCodes"

I come from a background in PHP and am trying to pick up VBA. I know this has to be some newbie thing I am doing but I have been researching this for the last hour or two.

All of your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `If dept = toSplitFileName(3) Then` isn't right. What should happen if this is true?

Comment: I want to start putting the results into an array if that is true. If it isn't true, it should just end the if statement and move back to the For Each until the For Each loop is complete.

Comment: If dept = toSplitFileName(3) Then

    Result(i) = MyFile.Name

Something like that..I can't get it to format it like code..sorry about that.

Comment: for each enumerator needs to have Collection object to enumerate. Can you show declaration of  `dept` and `deptCodes` objects?

Comment: i knew your mistacke brfore reading your code, since it's so common.
Your next is blocked by an unfinished if (...) then.
Also declaring variables inside a loop is not best practise.
The Msgbox is probably wrongly placed (and useless) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this. Assumes `Result` is declared appropriately.

```
Dim toSplitFileName As Variant

For Each MyFile In MyFiles
    If InStr(1, MyFile.Name, FileExt) <> 0 Then

        toSplitFileName = Split(MyFile.Name, "-")

        For Each dept In deptCodes
            MsgBox ("True")
            If dept = toSplitFileName(3) Then
                Result(i) = MyFile.Name
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next dept
    End If
Next MyFile
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot!